# EC2 Instance postgresql database error

Tags: amazon-ec2

I created a new EC2 instance from an image of a previous running instance. However on running the instance, I encountered an 500 error and on further investigation i found out this `OperationalError at /
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?`

What could have gone wrong since the previous instance was running correctly. Also, the instance is used to run a django app with the database running locally.

Also, on running `sudo service postgresql start` i got this error `* Starting PostgreSQL 9.1 database server                                       * Error: /mnt/data/postgresql/9.1/main is not accessible or does not exist`
 .
.
Running `pg_lsclusters` results to `Version Cluster   Port Status Owner    Data directory                     Log file
9.1     main      5432 down   <unknown> /mnt/data/postgresql/9.1/main      /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.1-main.log`

Any help most welcomed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
 rm -f /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

Also check the your `/etc/fstab file.  Is it mounting a /mnt/data directory ? Sounds like your data directory is not available where it was available on the original AWS instance.

Comment: While starting the postgresql, i get this Error: /mnt/data/postgresql/9.1/main is not accessible or does not exist Note: /mnt/data/postgresql/9.1/main is set as data_directory in postgresql.conf..

Comment: It's trying to find the /mnt/data/postgresql directory and it's not there. It was probably on the original instance that was used to create the Amazon AMI that you used to create this new instance. I suggest you check the original instance.

Comment: Thanks /mnt/ directory was the cause..I changed the postgresql.conf file to have the default postgres data_directory